# Bash script to calculate average of results from multiple runs of a python program

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to find the average result of a python program I wrote and currently wrote this script to first redirect the output to a file and then calculate the sum line by line in the file. Is there a way to remove the intermediary file and just sum over the output of stdout?

```
#!/bin/bash

> results

START=1
END=$1

for (( i=$START; i<=$END; i++ ))
do
    pypy3 test_qfl.py 0 9 250000 >> results
done


awk '{ SUM += $1; n++} END { if (n > 0) print SUM / n;}' results
```

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
#! /bin/sh -
n=${1?}
while [ "$n" -gt 0 ]; do
  pypy3 test_qfl.py 0 9 250000
  n=$(( n - 1 ))
done | awk '
  {sum += $1}
  END {if (NR) print sum / NR}'
```